# How to Set Text on the Left Side Just Below the Image in Android XML?

Tags: android, xml

I am Learning to create a Instagram Layout and I want to make Story Layout Text after the image But i dont know how to do it Here is Image below i want 'your story' just bottom of my image Please Help

To move Your Story at the bottom i add top margin and when i move to left side i tried to apply gravity but nothing works

### [enter image description here][1]

```
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center|center_horizontal"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView"
            android:layout_width="70dp"
            android:layout_height="70dp"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_camera_alt" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
            android:fontFamily="@font/bilbo_swash_caps"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:paddingRight="10dp"
            android:text="Instagram"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textSize="40sp" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imaggView2"
            android:layout_width="70dp"
            android:layout_height="70dp"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_message" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <View
        android:id="@+id/view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:background="@color/black"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/horizontalScrollView"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/linearLayout"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.309" />

    <HorizontalScrollView
        android:id="@+id/horizontalScrollView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="23dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/linearLayout"
        tools:ignore="SpeakableTextPresentCheck">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="100dp">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView1"
                android:layout_width="70dp"
                android:layout_height="70dp"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/playstore" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="80dp"
                android:text="Your Story"
                />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView2"
                android:layout_width="70dp"
                android:layout_height="70dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/playstore" />


            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView3"
                android:layout_width="70dp"
                android:layout_height="70dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/playstore" />


            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageVie"
                android:layout_width="70dp"
                android:layout_height="70dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/playstore" />


            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imagew4"
                android:layout_width="70dp"
                android:layout_height="70dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/playstore" />


            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imad4"
                android:layout_width="70dp"
                android:layout_height="70dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/playstore" />


            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imagsdsw4"
                android:layout_width="70dp"
                android:layout_height="70dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/playstore" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imadd"
                android:layout_width="70dp"
                android:layout_height="70dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/playstore" />


            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imcsew4"
                android:layout_width="70dp"
                android:layout_height="70dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/playstore" />


            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imagdd4"
                android:layout_width="70dp"
                android:layout_height="70dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/playstore" />


            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/f"
                android:layout_width="70dp"
                android:layout_height="70dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/playstore" />


            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imagebb4"
                android:layout_width="70dp"
                android:layout_height="70dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/playstore" />

        </LinearLayout>
    </HorizontalScrollView>



  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/7kA9C.png
```

Answer (score 0):

If I am not mistaken, do you just want to set the `textview` of 'Your Store' below the `imageview1`?

Firstly, we should know the characteristics of LinearLayout.

```
<LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView1"
                android:layout_width="70dp"
                android:layout_height="70dp"
                app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round" />                       

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="80dp"
                android:text="Your Story" />

... ...
 </LinearLayout>
```

It means that the `imageview1` and the `textview` are side by side.
Obviously, the 'Your Story' couldn't be directly below the `imageview1`

Secondly, if you want to implement the UI, look like this: a `Textview` is directly below a picture.
Simply, you can use Textview contains a drawable with `android:drawableTop`

```
<LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView1"
                android:layout_width="70dp"
                android:layout_height="70dp"
                app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:drawableTop="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:drawablePadding="10dp"
                android:text="Your Story" />
......
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:gravity="center">

               <ImageView
                 android:id="@+id/imageView1"
                 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                 app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round" />

               <TextView
                 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                 android:textColor="@color/black"
                 android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
                 android:text="Your Story" />

</LinearLayout>
```

You Need To add Just orientation(vertical) And gravity(center) In Your Parent layout...